# c# crash on conversion, apparently null?

Tags: c#

I am trying to draw an image to a picturebox (`pbImage`) and convert it into a bitmap after but it crashes because `pcImage.Image` is apperently`null`, I can see the drawing before it crashes so I don't understand how it is `null`.

Here is the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'     occurred in System.Drawing.dll  Additional information: Object reference not set to an   instance of an object.

```
bool[,] bCollision = new bool[pbImage.Width,pbImage.Height];
Color cPixelCol;
Graphics G = Graphics.FromHwnd(pbImage.Handle);
Pen SquarePen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
SquarePen = new Pen(Color.Red, 5);
Brush BackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Aqua);
G.FillRectangle(BackBrush, 50, 50, this.Width, this.Height);
G.DrawLine(SquarePen, 410, 50, 410, 400);
G.DrawEllipse(SquarePen, 50 + x, 50, 100+x, 50);
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(pbImage.Image);   <------------- this line crashes
```

Comment: My guess, `pbImage.Image` is null. Anyway, we are not here to debug your code, had you tried a bit  finding the cause you would have made it in less than 20 seconds, that's why I downvoted the question.

Comment: `pbImage.Image` is never set in this code... so it is probably null...

Comment: Try to access `pbImage.Image` before creating the Graphics and see if it is null

Comment: If `pbImage.Image` was null, you should see an ArgumentNullException. I can't promise that you will, but that's what's suppose to happen. For my money, any `NullReferenceException` is a bug in the library being called.

Comment: @JonathanAllen Exactly. Either the parameter is optional, in which case no exception should be thrown, or it's mandatory, and the lib should throw an `ArgumentNullException` that tells you what is null and shouldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"I can see the drawing before it crashes so I don't understand how it is null."

Yes, because you drew the image to the **SCREEN** with:

```
Graphics G = Graphics.FromHwnd(pbImage.Handle);
```

This is simply drawing "on top" of the PictureBox to a **temporary** graphics.  Anything drawn this way would simply be erased if you passed another window over it.  Nothing was actually assigned to the Image() property of the PictureBox.

Why don't you start by creating a Bitmap, then getting a Graphics from that?  Afterwards you can assign that Bitmap to your PictureBox:

```
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pbImage.Width, pbImage.Height); // not sure what widht/height you really need
        using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            using (Pen SquarePen = new Pen(Color.Red, 5))
            {
                G.Clear(Color.Aqua);
                G.DrawLine(SquarePen, 410, 50, 410, 400);
                G.DrawEllipse(SquarePen, 50 + x, 50, 100 + x, 50);
            }
        }
        pbImage.Image = bmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but I think you need to release the Graphics object before you use the Image. Try this...

```
G.DrawEllipse(SquarePen, 50 + x, 50, 100+x, 50);
G.Dispose();
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(pbImage.Image);
```